# If $20\%$ of $45\%$ of a positive number is equal to $x$ percent of $0.3$ percent of the same number what is the value of $x$?

Tags: percentages

I have tried setting up an equation and cross multiplying but it is not one of the answer choices.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? (What was your equation, what answer did you get?)

Comment: @Turtle Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit next time how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. If not probably you will receive down votes to your question. Here is a guide to write mathematical expressions with Mathjax:  
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the worded problem into an equation, yield this below expression, out of which you can cancel out $p$ from both sides to get $x$.

$.20\times.45\times p=x\%\times0.3\%\times p\\
\implies0.09\times100\times100=x\times0.3\\
\implies x=3000$

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the equation and cross multiplying, but as it was said in the comments, please for future questions if possible add always what you tried to do to solve the problem.

Unless I misunderstood the problem, I would do as follows, $n \gt 0$ is the positive number:

$\frac{20}{100}\cdot\frac{45}{100}\cdot n = \frac{x}{100}\cdot \frac{0.3}{100}\cdot n$

is the same as:

$\frac{20\cdot 45}{100\cdot 100}\cdot n = \frac{x\cdot 0.3}{100\cdot 100}\cdot n$

both sides are multiplied by $n$ and divided by $100\cdot 100$, so it is possible to simplify:

$20\cdot 45 = x\cdot 0.3$

finally:

$x=\frac{20\cdot45}{0.3}=3000$

Comment: Thank you for solving my question! And thanks for the tips, this was my first question I asked :)

Comment: @Turtle my pleasure! if you like my answer you can up vote it and click the V mark so the question is marked as answered and will be considered "closed" (meaning already "answered"). :)